# <div> element falls outside of border

Tags: css

I'm trying to draw the black border around `Test1` - `Test4` to also span around `Test5`. At the moment, `Test5` falls outside. Does anyone know how to draw it to include `Test5`?

```css
.description {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.descriptionTop {
  display: inline-block;
}

.ao {
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

.pr {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}

.pm {
  border: solid 1px #53a318;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #53a318;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
  padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <div class="descriptionTop">
    <span class="descriptionLeft">Test1</span>
    <span class="ao">Test2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="pr">
    <div>
      <span>Test3</span>
      <span>Test4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="pm">Test5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto;` to the container to include floated elements:

```css
.description {
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.descriptionTop {
  display: inline-block;
}

.altOffer {
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

.prices {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}

.promotion {
  border: solid 1px #53a318;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #53a318;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
  padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <div class="descriptionTop">
    <span class="descriptionLeft">Test1</span>
    <span class="altOffer">Test2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="prices">
    <div>
      <span>Test3</span>
      <span>Test4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="promotion">Test5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `.prices` has `float`. [Explanation of the problem](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp)

add the following to your css (the `css` of famous `clearfix` class) -

```
.description:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```css
.description {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.description:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.descriptionTop {
  display: inline-block;
}

.ao {
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

.pr {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}

.pm {
  border: solid 1px #53a318;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #53a318;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
  padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <div class="descriptionTop">
    <span class="descriptionLeft">Test1</span>
    <span class="ao">Test2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="pr">
    <div>
      <span>Test3</span>
      <span>Test4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="pm">Test5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```